# C# Reflection - COM objects

Tags: c#, reflection, com

If I had a COM object (instanced with Activator.CreateInstance) that exposes other objects as properties, like

`Object1.Object2.Object3`

How can I get Object3 if I only have an instance of Object1 using reflection?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get Object3 if I only have an instance of Object1 using reflection?

That's impossible. You need to first get the `Object2` instance via reflection and only after that you can access `Object3`. That might have been possible if you had some other object that is holding reference to `Object3`.

By the way if you are using .NET 4.0 or later you may find that the `dynamic` keyword might save you lots of hassles when dealing with COM objects and reflection. Check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading about the wonders of `dynamic` late binding in 4.0, but unfortunately, I'm on .NET 3.5... :(

Comment: Oh, sorry to here that. By the way you could use VB.NET which doesn't have the same strict typing as C#. It's much easier to work with COM objects in VB.NET than it is in C# (before the dynamic keyword of course). So basically you could encapsulate this logic into a .NET assembly written in VB.NET that your other parts of code could access. If you cannot do that, then I am afraid that you have to prepare yourself for hardcore reflection stuff.